# нужна помощь по задаче по классам с использованием try - except

Tags: python, классы, исключения, try

Нужно создать программу, в которой я ввожу свои данные через консоль, и заполняю массив пользователей.

Есть класс пользователей **User**
str name
str surname
int age

А также конструктор для всех параметров.

В главном классе, то есть основной части, должен быть список пользователей, с максимальным размером 5 человек. Моя программа должна запрашивать пользователя ввести этих 5 пользователей через консоль.

**Однако,  если я во время введения возраста введу неверные данные (не целое число), то программа должна автоматом ввести число 0 в поле возраста и добавить объект в список.**

В конце ввода  программа должна вывести среднее значение возраста в списке.

вот мой код:

```
class User:
    name = ""
    surname = ""
    age = 0

    def __init__(self, name, surname, age):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age

def result(self):
    count = 0
    sum_age = 0
    self.average = 0
    for i in users:
        sum_age += i.age
        count += 1
    self.average = sum_age / count
    print(self.average)

print('Input 5 users:')

u1 = User(input('Name: '), input('Surname: '), input('Age: '))
u2 = User(input('Name: '), input('Surname: '), input('Age: '))
u3 = User(input('Name: '), input('Surname: '), input('Age: '))
u4 = User(input('Name: '), input('Surname: '), input('Age: '))
u5 = User(input('Name: '), input('Surname: '), input('Age: '))

users = [u1, u2, u3, u4, u5]

for i in users:
    try:

    except:



for j in users:
    j.result()
```

*я не могу понять как прописать в try except это условие* **"Однако,  если я во время введения возраста введу неверные данные (не целое число), то программа должна автоматом ввести число 0 в поле возраста и добавить объект в список."**

*и почему у меня не выводится средний возраст*

Comment: Целое, а не целостное

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы немного перемудрили. проверять возраст лучше сразу при создании объекта. Вычисление среднего возраста, по сути, не должно быть методом объекта

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, name, surname, age):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        try:
            self.age = int(age)
        except ValueError:
            self.age = 0

print('Input 5 users:')

u1 = User(input('Name: '), input('Surname: '), input('Age: '))
u2 = User(input('Name: '), input('Surname: '), input('Age: '))
u3 = User(input('Name: '), input('Surname: '), input('Age: '))
u4 = User(input('Name: '), input('Surname: '), input('Age: '))
u5 = User(input('Name: '), input('Surname: '), input('Age: '))

users = [u1, u2, u3, u4, u5]

sum_age = 0
for u in users:
    sum_age += u.age

print(sum_age/len(users))
```

Ну и ввод данных можете сделать попроще, чтоб не дублировать код

```
count = 5
print(f'Input {count} users:')

users = [User(input('Name: '), input('Surname: '), input('Age: ')) for _ in range(count)]
```

Comment: `sum` - встроенная функция питона, не перекрывайте его, назовите переменную `summ` или `sum_`: `summ = sum(u.age for u in users)`

Comment: да, это я прозевал

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! @splash58